# c++ template template infer type arguments

Tags: c++, templates

I have a base type

```
template<int p> 
struct Base {};
```

and a more complex stuff built upon many versions of Base (some are int-templates, some are class-templates):

```
template<template<auto inner> typename basetype, typename p, typename q>
struct Complex {};
```

Then, i create variable like that :

```
Complex<Base, Base<1>, Base<2>> c;
```

is there a way to infer my first template parameter is `Base`, or that `p` and `q` are specialized version of `basetype`so I could write

```
Complex<Base<1>, Base<2>> c;
```

I guess there isn't. But templates hide some magic sometimes.

Comment: Why do you need this first parameter at all? There are way to get the template from a type, i.e. deduce `Base` from `Base<1>`. If that works for you, I can post an answer on how to do this.

Comment: because i need to instanciate basetype on other values somewhere. But I'd love to see how you infer Base from Base<1>.

Comment: Are `p` and `q` always going to be specializations of `basetype`?

Comment: @MrPromethee yes

Comment: To me it looks like you want a template that would allow you to do `Complex<Base, 1, 2> c;` instead?

Comment: One up-vote for the good question. I posted an answer. Please let me know if it needs further explanations.

Answer (score 9):

If you want `Complex` to always have its two arguments be specializations of the same template, then you can achieve this using partial specialization:

```
// the primary template remains incomplete, so most uses of it will be an error
template <class T, class U> struct Complex;

template <template<auto> typename basetype, auto p_arg, auto q_arg>
struct Complex<basetype<p_arg>, basetype<q_arg>> {
    // ...
};
```

When you instantiate `Complex<Base<1>, Base<2>>`, the arguments `basetype`, `p_arg`, and `q_arg` will be deduced as `Base`, `1`, and `2`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming that it is still preferable to maintain an option to enter the base class template manually, there is a way to infer the base class template automatically, with a small modification.

The order of the template parameters should change to let the base class template to be inferred from a default argument:

```
template<typename p, typename q, template<auto> class basetype = Complex_helper<p, q>::template base>
struct Complex {};
```

And adding a helper template like:

```
template<template<auto> class basetype, auto p, auto q>
struct Complex_helper<basetype<p>, basetype<q> >{
    template<auto x>
    using base = basetype<x>;
};
```

Which (by using specialization) will provide a [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) for the `Base` (`base`), or any other class template if both of its type-parameters are driven from `a same class template.

Putting it all together:

```
template<int p>
struct Base {};
template<int p>
struct Another_Base {};

template<typename, typename>
struct Complex_helper;
template<template<auto> class basetype, auto p, auto q>
struct Complex_helper<basetype<p>, basetype<q> >{
    template<auto x>
    using base = basetype<x>;
};

template<typename p, typename q, template<auto> class basetype = Complex_helper<p, q>::template base>
struct Complex {};

Complex<Base<1>, Base<2> > object1;
Complex<Another_Base<7>, Another_Base<8> > object2;

Complex<Base<5>, Base<8>, Base> object3;
Complex<Another_Base<2>, Another_Base<9>,  Another_Base> object4;

Complex<Base<78>, Base<87>, Another_Base> object5;
Complex<Another_Base<29>, Another_Base<92>,  Base> object6;
```

As you can see you can also enter the class template manually.

Good luck!